# Can't Add Slash with .htaccess

Tags: apache, url, .htaccess, apache2, backslash

I have a site with some html files on it. One of them is contact.html. This is my .htaccess, and I'm having problems where I can address the page with site.com/contact, but not site.com/contact/. (Note ending slash.) What's the fix?

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the requested URI does not contain a period in the final path-part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
# and if it does not exist as a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
# and if it does not exist as a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
# then add .html to get the actual filename
rewriterule (.*) /$1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
rewriterule (.*) /$1.html [L]
```

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: That fixed it. I just had to make certain to look for all relative pathing with src, href, and image links and switch them to fixed pathing.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

In my case, I will remove slash before $1 and it works! I'm appreciate to learn a great deal from your comment.